# In Pyramid how can I redirect from http to https?

Tags: python, pyramid

If you don't have access to the webserver, and the only way you have is to intercept the request and then do a redirect from http to https, what is the best approach to redirect?

I tried looking at subscribers using NewRequest. I did something like so:

> ```
> @subscriber(NewRequest)
> def modify_protocol(event):
>     if re.search('some string', event.request.host_url):
>         event.request.scheme = 'https'
> ```

However, this didn't do what I expected. The page is still being rendered. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Inside a view:

```
if req.scheme == "http":
        return HTTPFound("https://" + req.host + req.path_qs)
```

Using an event listener:

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def redirect(event):
    if event.request.scheme == "http":
        raise HTTPFound("https://" + event.request.host + event.request.path_qs)
```

I looked into approaches using `send` and `get_response`, but couldn't find much.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I still think that the best solution is modifying the web server config file to make a rewrite when http is hit. I was just wondering how you could accomplish this at the application level.

I tried this, and it does not work. :( I had high hopes.

Comment: Are you saying what I posted doesn't work? I tested both variants, they worked well.

Comment: This works, just make sure that 'req' is replaced with the request object you passed into your view. In my case, i use the whole word 'request' so it becomes request.scheme, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some unsolicited advice - Don't redirect to SSL from non-SSL.

There's a security issue. Basically, if someone manages to Man-In-The-Middle your non-SSL'd service, they could redirect it to an SSL service running with a valid certificate on a different server - the user might not notice this.

It's better to provide a page that warns the user and provides a plain-text link for them to click.

Comment: Good advice, but https links on an http page are as easily compromised as redirects.

Comment: Eh. At least the user is engaged enough to understand that they're not SSL'd and have to click the URL. Any time I click an explicitly stated URL I always double check the URL bar. When I get magically directed I just continue browsing. I'd rather have a little bit of feedback and do a little legwork myself than get auto-redirected and not be offered the opportunity. You might run into a middle-manager or "javascript" guy that makes an argument about ease of use for users, but - Secure websites are better than customers getting MITM'd.

Comment: I'm with you, but any text can be replaced on the insecure page, so there's always the threat of a MITM attack without any notice to the user (they wouldn't even see the plaintext link, for example). HSTS is the best we've got so far, OWASP has given up on recommending against redirects because http is always going to be an open vector.